# How can I compile and build a program using external library with command line tools come with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, terminal, clang++

I am coding a computer vision program, which is using OpenCV 2.4, by Xcode 4.4. I want to compile and make it in the Terminal by g++ or make command. But the system shows a lot of errors that the compiler cannot find the "opencv2/opencv.hpp" file and Vec3d, etc..!

My question is how to configure the system the I can make and build the code in Terminal? Thanks.

Comment: You want to set your development sysroot. `g++ -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/` etc.

Comment: I am not coding this program to iOS platform. It's just an OpenCV-based vision code running on command-line manner.

Comment: then substitute iPhoneOS5.1.sdk to MacOSX10.7.SDK (or 6, or 8, ...) respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have command line tools (I guess you already have it)

1. Bring up Preference in Xcode
2. Select "Downloads" tab
3. Select "Components' tab
4. Click 'install' on the command line tools line.

Then, you need to install OpenCV. I suggest to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

1. setup homebrew, then
2. `brew install opencv`

It will install library in /usr/local, which is in g++'s standard lookup path, thus should be ok.

If you still need help, post the log file.

Comment: I got the following messages: "In file included from main.cpp:1:
slic.h:4:30: error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory" I install the opencv by macports.

Comment: Try run: `mdfind -name opencv.hpp`. If it's in /usr/local or below, then the option you configure the your `computer vision program` is wrong. I suspect it is configuring include path to somewhere normal. too see that, you need to show the log. above information is not enough to find out what is going on..

Comment: It shows the "opencv.hpp" file in "/opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp". I use "ln" command to link the "include" folder to the one in "/usr/include" but it does not work. And later I "ln" the "/opt/local/lib" to the one in "usr/lib" but it also does not work.

Comment: As I said, Log is important. the point is, how the program's configuration framework decides where opencv is. It will be decided on configuration, or might be stay in part of Makefile (which you need to edit). All of them ultimately reflected as g++'s option. To see what's going on, need to see actual g++'s arguments. without that, I can't help well.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how to obtain the log file? I am a beginner in unix-like system.

Comment: Use script command to collect log as a file, then, if the log is huge, paste them as a gist at gist.github.com and paste the link of the gist here.

script command start a new shell. All of the output onto your terminal will be in the file. exiting the shell by `exit` shell command will close the log file. you can specify the log file name by running for example: `script /tmp/LOG_FILE_NAME` Of course you can cut&paste whole terminal output. To paste to gist, just open gist.github.com and paste, you'll have the link to the file.

Comment: If log is not so log (say, < 100 lines) you can paste it as part of above question.

Comment: Hi, I make the gist at git://gist.github.com/3269164.git . Thanks.

Comment: OK, then, in Makefile, there should be `CFLAGS` definition. add `-I/opt/local/include` and try again.

Comment: If you can't find `CFLAGS` then just define it. like: `CFLAGS = -I/opt/locla/include`

Comment: Hi, sorry for that I am not familar with the Makefile composition. Here is mine git://gist.github.com/3269950.git . I failed to pass the "make".

Comment: Actually, you overrode rule for g++ so you have to include the path directly in the g++ command line. I used `CXXFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS` because it's g++. If you do not override rules, if you define `CFLAGS`, it will be used both for g++ and gcc(cc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly help. I use your new makefile and it shows new error messages on Architecture x86_64. A gist at git://gist.github.com/3270200.git . Is that caused by the program variable type not support the 64-bit system? Thanks.

Comment: No, I suspect the library you built via MacPorts are in 32bit. You must match the options used by the CV library and the program you're writing. Consult the opencv build process and copy the appropriate options to the Makefile

Comment: No, it's 64-bit version by Macports. Please see http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port/ . I used this method to build.

Comment: I changed the Makefile by adding an argument "-arch x86_64" in the g++ command line. Please see a gist at git://gist.github.com/3271087.git . But it shows two lines error messages at git://gist.github.com/3271092.git

Comment: Hi, I solve the problem. just use the command: g++ ${CXXFLAGS} main.cpp slic.cpp -o slic -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib  -lopencv_core.2.4.2 -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.2 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.2, where the arguments "-I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib" are important. Thanks for your kindly help!:)